# Why is Oracle Pivot producing non-existent results?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I manage a database holding a large amount of climate data collected from various stations. It's an Oracle 12.2 DB, and here's a synopsis of the relevant tables:

FACT = individual measurements at a particular time

- UTC_START = time in UTC at which the measurement began
- LST_START = time in local standard time (to the particular station) at which the measurement began
- SERIES_ID = ID of the series to which the measurement belongs (FK to SERIES)
- STATION_ID = ID of the station at which the measurement occurred (FK to STATION)
- VALUE = value of the measurement

Note that UTC_START and LST_START always have a constant difference per station (the LST offset from UTC). I have confirmed that there are no instances where the difference between UTC_START and LST_START is anything other than what is expected.

SERIES = descriptive data for series of data

- SERIES_ID = ID of the series (PK)
- NAME = text name of the series (e.g. Temperature)

STATION = descriptive data for stations

- STATION_ID = ID of the station (PK)
- SITE_ID = ID of the site at which a station is located (most sites have one station, but a handful have 2)
- SITE_RANK = rank of the station within the site if there are more than 1 stations.
- EXT_ID = external ID for a site (provided to us)

The EXT_ID of a site applies to all stations at that site (but may not be populated unless SITE_RANK == 1, not ideal, I know, but not the issue here), and data from lower ranked stations is preferred. To organize this data into a consumable format, we're using a PIVOT to collect measurements occurring at the same site/time into rows.

Here's the query:

```
WITH
    primaries AS (
        SELECT site_id, ext_id
        FROM station
        WHERE site_rank = 1
    ),

    data as (
        SELECT d.site_id, d.utc_start, d.lst_start, s.name, d.value FROM (
            SELECT s.site_id, f.utc_start, f.lst_start, f.series_id, f.value,
                 ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY s.site_id, f.utc_start, f.series_id ORDER BY s.site_rank) as ORDINAL
                 FROM fact f
                      JOIN station s on f.station_id = s.station_id
        ) d
            JOIN series s ON d.series_id = s.series_id
            WHERE d.ordinal = 1
                AND d.site_id = ?
                AND d.utc_start >= ?
                AND d.utc_start < ?
    )

    records as (

        SELECT * FROM data
        PIVOT (
               MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE
               FOR NAME IN (
                   -- these are a few series that we would want to collect by UTC_START
                   't5' as t5,
                   'p5' as p5,
                   'solrad' as solrad,
                   'str' as str,
                   'stc_05' as stc_05,
                   'rh' as rh,
                   'smv005_05' as smv005_05,
                   'st005_05' as st005_05,
                   'wind' as wind,
                   'wet1' as wet1
                   )
                )
    )

SELECT r.*, p.ext_id
FROM records r JOIN primaries p on r.site_id = p.site_id
```

Here's where things get odd. This query works perfectly in SQLAlchemy, IntelliJ (using OJDBC thin), and Orcale SQL Developer. But when it's run from within our Java program (same JDBC urls, and credentials, using plain old JDBC statments and result sets), it gives results that don't make sense. Specifically for the same station, it will return 2 rows with the same UTC_START, but different LST_START (recall that I have verified that this 100% does not occur anywhere in the FACT table). Just to ensure there was no weird parameter handling going on, we tested hard-coding values in for the placeholders, and copy-and-pasted the exact same query between various clients, and the only one that returns these strange results is the Java program (which is using the exact same OJDBC jar as IntelliJ).

If anyone has any insight or possible causes, it would be greatly appreciated. We're at a bit of a loss right now.

Comment: What are the data types of  `UTC_START` and `LST_START`? It sounds like some conversion due to difference in time zone..

Comment: They're both DATE, but LST_START is simply UTC_START plus the UTC offset (i.e. it's calculated from UTC_START, not observed directly). And I've already verified that UTC_START and LST_START have the appropriate difference for every single row in FACT. There's actually no explicit timezone conversion per se, it's just a simple addition operation

Comment: Try to use /*+ MATERIALIZE \*/ or /*+ INLINE */ hints into the CTE query. If the very same SQL returns different results, depending on Exec. plan, then is it definitely Oracle BUG. There were some nasty bugs in a new way on GROUP BY evaluation, when 12c version was introduced.

Comment: @ibre5041 same thing happens with either hint. On the note of exec plans, the steps are the same when running through IntelliJ or Java, but the estimated costs from the Java version are substantially smaller for some reason

Comment: So even plan hash value is the same? But the cost is different?

Comment: Apologies, looks like I was mistaken on that one. Plan steps, hash, and cost are all the same.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with the way the Java program is displaying or outputting the resulting data, rather than the data returned from Oracle being incorrect?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am. In order to debug this, I have Java spitting out results directly from the result set (using .getString to avoid conversions) with no ORM of any sort

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [Nathan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093282/why-is-oracle-pivot-producing-non-existent-results#comment104426058_59093282) was correct. Though it seems counter-intuitive (to me, at least), it appears that calling ResultSet.getString on a DATE column will in fact convert to Timestamp first. Timestamp has the unfortunate default behavior of using the system default timezone unless you specify otherwise explicitly.

This default behavior meant that daylight saving's time was taken into account when we didn't intend it to be, leading to the odd behavior described.